# Unable to get value from json object

Tags: javascript, ajax, json

I am trying to get a value from a json object after making an ajax call. Not sure what I am doing wrong it seems straight forward but not able to get the data

The data that comes back looks like this

```
{"data":"[{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"D\\u0027Costa\"}]"}
```

The code, removed some of the code

```
.ajax({

     type: 'POST',
     url: "http://localhost:1448/RegisterDetails/",
     dataType: 'json',
     data: { "HomeID": self.Id, "Name": $("#txtFamilyName").val()},
       success: function (result) {
       console.log(result.data);  //<== the data show here like above
       alert(result.data.Id);  //<==nothing show
     },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

     }
   });
```

I tried in the Chrome console like this

```
obj2 = {}
Object {}
obj2 = {"data":"[{\"Id\":3,\"Name\":\"D\\u0027Costa\"}]"}
Object {data: "[{"Id":3,"Name":"D\u0027Costa"}]"}
obj2.data
"[{"Id":3,"Name":"D\u0027Costa"}]"
obj2.data.Id
undefined
obj2.Id
undefined
```

**Update**

The line that solved the issue as suggested here is

```
var retValue = JSON.parse(result.data)[0]
```

Now I can used

```
retValue.Name
```

to get the value

Comment: data is actually an array from the looks of it. try doing JSON.parse of result

Comment: `JSON.parse(jsonData.data)[0].Id`

Comment: I just tried a jsfiddle doing the JSON parse, and it has an error parsing the values, what is used to encode the JSON in the first place?

Comment: I am not too sure what you mean to encode

Comment: The server side function that turns your data into json, are you using PHP or ASP.NET MVC or an API endpoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data field is just a string, you should parse it to a JSON object with `JSON.parse(result.data)`, since data is now an array you will need to need to use an index `[0]` to have access to the object. Know you will be able to get the `Id` property.

```
JSON.parse(result.data)[0].Id
```

Comment: The only thing is, if you try that JSON in a fiddle, the `JSON.parse` comes back with an error.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, looking at this, my best guess is that you're missing `JSON.parse()`

```
.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: "http://localhost:1448/RegisterDetails/",
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { "HomeID": self.Id, "Name": $("#txtFamilyName").val()},
    success: function (result) {

        var javascriptObject = JSON.parse(result);

        console.log(javascriptObject );  //<== the data show here like above
        alert(javascriptObject.Id);  //<==nothing show
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

    }
});
```

I also find that doing `ajax` requests like this is better:

```
var result = $.ajax({
    url: "someUrl",
    data: { some: "data" },
    method: "POST/GET"
});

result.done(function (data, result) {
    if (result == "success") { // ajax success
        var data = JSON.parse(data);

        //do something here
    }
});
```

For clarity it just looks better, also copying and pasting into different functions as well is better.

Comment: I tried  var javascriptObject = JSON.parse(result); and got this error  **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token o**

Comment: Then I tried  var javascriptObject = JSON.parse(result.data);                       console.log(javascriptObject);  No error but still cannot access Name

Comment: yeah, I think your JSON is either malformed, or needs some extra processing. Check where it comes from.

Comment: I got it to work like this.  JSON.parse(result.data)[0]  Updated my question with the working code

Answer (score 1):

The `id` property is in the first element of the data-*array*. So, `alert(result.data[0].Id)` should give the desired result. Just for the record: there is no such thing as a 'JSON-object'. You can parse a JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) *string* to a Javascript Object, which [parsing] supposedly is handled by the `.ajax` method here.

Comment: `data` is a `string` which looks like an array. You should parse this string first